# How to get Python to remember user input between classes?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner, working on a text-based game like lots of beginners seem to. I'm using the game structure used in Learn Python The Hard Way, where each scene of the game is its own class. Here is what I mean: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex43.html

My problem: I want the player to name the main character via a prompt, and for that name to be remembered and recalled throughout the game. As shown above, the progression of the game is through a series of classes. Using the only input memorization method I know so far, the name received from the user's raw input is only memorized for one class (scene), and then forgotten in the next. I don't even know where to begin on figuring out how to fix this so that the name will carry on throughout the whole game/series of classes- what terms to search, what to research more, etc.

The only method I know right now for remembering/recalling things like names is the

```
name = raw_input ("Name: ")
print "My name is %s" % name
```

kind of thing. That doesn't continue through classes, so it's forgotten by the next "scene."

Comment: I would create a data object that I could pass between classes. (this could even be a `dict`). This would contain otherwise global values.

Answer (score 2):

Very generally: obviously, you need to save this data outside your class. You can do this one of several ways:

1. You can save it into a global variable
2. you can save it to a separate class or variable that gets passed around.

More of a philosophical question for you: what about the "thing" that is the "scene" in your game requires the user's name? Sounds like this prompt belongs somewhere else. You shold compartmentalize things into classes that "belong" together. Maybe have a "user" class?

Comment: Alright, so I need to research some more on global variables and how to save user data, it looks like. I had a feeling global variables might be helpful, but I didn't find any guides or explanations thorough enough to explain how to store data received by user input. Do you happen to know of any?

Comment: What your asking is a fundamental program structure question, and I imagine it is addressed thoroughly in LPTH. If that tutorial doesn't satisfy you, look up other introductory programming tutorials. I recommend MIT OCW introduction to programming.